# display or append element via scope variable in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to [Angular.js](http://www.angular.js.org) which is why this question might be a very basic one but I would like to know how I can display elements via `$scope`.
Very simple:

```
<div id="view" ng-controller="images">{{ image }}</div>
```

and

```
function images($scope) {
  $scope.image = '<img src="img/file.png">';
}
```

in this example it will only display the image tag as a string. Obviously one could to

```
<div id="view" ng-controller="images"><img src="{{ image }}"></div>
```

and use the source as variable

```
$scope.image = 'img/file.png';
```

but thats not what I am searching for. Is it possible to display elements as DOM element, not as a string.

Comment: Actually, you *"can't"* do `<img src="{{ image }}">` because the dom will be loaded before the `{{ image }}` will be evaluated (or something like that. You have to use `ng-src`. I know thats not your question but i just wanted to let you know before you go on

Comment: Now, to answer you question, what you want to look up is a directive. Thats at least what I would do based on what you are asking.

Comment: I tried `<img src="{{ image }}">` and it works fine though.

Comment: yes it works, but its buggy and won't work every time. See here --> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a directive (basically a template of sorts) to do what you want.

So you have your app with your controller and your directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ImagesController', function($scope) {
        $scope.image = '/url/to/my/img.png';
    })
    .directive('showImage', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: 'true',
            templates: '<img ng-src="{{ image }}">'
        };
    })
```

and then in your html you would have something like so:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <body>
        <div id="view" ng-controller="ImagesController">
            <show-image></show-image>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`<show-image` would then be replaced with the template within the directive, `<img ng-src="{{ image }}">`

Answer (score 1):

according to the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

you have to bind it as html

```
 <div ng-bind-html="imagesafe"></div>
```

in your controller you have to sanitize the variable

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.image = '<img src="img/file.png">';
    $scope.imagesafe =  $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.image);
}
```